# Связка нескольких языков программирования (php + python)

Tags: php, python, веб-программирование, composer

Понимаю, что это не ново, но хочется понимать насколько это адекватно или как поступают в таких случаях.

Есть проект на PHP, в котором потребовалось доставать текст из файлов любых форматов. Набор классов для извлечения текста вылилось в свой пакет для composer. В PHP я столкнулся с тем, что нет толковых библиотек для этого. Пробовал PhpOffice и подобные, но все они имеют свои сложности и недоработки, поэтому пришлось искать иные решения.

Посоветовали посмотреть линуксовые и Python пакеты и обнаружил библиотеку Tika для Python, которая блестяще справляется с задачей. Но решение необходимо на PHP, поэтому я увидел только одно решение - в нужных методах PHP вызывать exec с командой выполнения Python-скрипта с вызовом этой библиотеки (по такой же аналогии можно вызвать линуксовые пакеты вроде catdoc или antiword).

Меня интересует адекватность подобного решения и способы решения таких ситуаций, поскольку само по себе оно кажется странным в том плане, что если создавать из этого пакет композера (не обязательно, просто как идея), то в нем нельзя указать зависимости python или линукса. А смотреть исходники библиотеки и пытаться написать все на PHP у меня недостаточно знаний.

Comment: Я вам хотел посоветовать написать расширение к php, но если вы не знаток php, то в с++ вообще не разберётесь. Если ваше решение работает, то оно хорошее до тех пор, пока вы не найдёте лучше. В вызове `exec` нет ничего плохого

Comment: @ArchDemon Вы имеете ввиду написать на C++ расширение, которое будет делать тоже самое, что и библиотека на python, о которой я писал в задаче?

Comment: нет. Написать расширение php на с++, которое будет дёргать библиотеку на python. С точки зрения php всё будет выглядеть канонично